# Item index must be a number error

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile app using  sqlite for storage. The function below successfully retrieved the result from a database query

```
function querySuccess(tx,result){

    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index);

    });

}
```

I was using jquery v1.6.4. However when I updated jquery to v1.9.1 I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Item index must be a number."

Comment: Would you please stop writing tags in titles?

Comment: The second parameter to your callback function is the object you want I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
function querySuccess(tx,result){

    $.each(result.rows,function(index, row){
        // Do what you want with your row variable here...

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that I'm still getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Item index must be a number'

Comment: Which line is that happening on?

Comment: on this one: var row = result.rows.item(index) - the code being -


function querySuccess(tx,result){

    $.each(result.rows,function(index, row){
     var row = result.rows.item(index)

    });

}

Comment: Just use "row" instead of using var row.